# A corollary of commutation theorem for tensor product of von Neumann algebras.

Tags: tensor-products, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Please help me to understand the proof of the following corollary from the book 'Lectures on von Neumann algebras' by Stratila and Zsido.

**Corollary:** Let $\mathscr{M}_1$ and $\mathscr{M}_2$ be von Neumann algebras, $\mathscr{Z}_1,\,\mathscr{Z}_2$ their centers, respectively. Then the center of $\mathscr{M}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2$ is $\mathscr{Z}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{Z}_2$.

To prove the corollary, they have used the commutation theorem for tensor products (i.e. for two von Neumann algebras $\mathscr{M}_1$ and $\mathscr{M}_2$, we have $(\mathscr{M}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2)'=\mathscr{M}_1'\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2'$). Here is my attempt to understand the proof.

Let $\mathscr{Z}$ be the center of $\mathscr{M}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2$. Then $$\mathscr{Z}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{Z}_2=(\mathscr{M}_1\cap\mathscr{M}_1')\overline{\otimes}(\mathscr{M}_2\cap\mathscr{M}_2')\subseteq (\mathscr{M}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2)\cap(\mathscr{M}_1'\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2')=(\mathscr{M}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2)\cap(\mathscr{M}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2)'=\mathscr{Z}.$$
Now conversely, we have to prove $\mathscr{Z}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{Z}_2\supseteq\mathscr{Z}$, i.e. $(\mathscr{Z}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{Z}_2)'\subseteq\mathscr{Z}'$, i.e. $\mathscr{Z}_1'\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{Z}_2'\subseteq\mathscr{Z}'$, i.e. $\mathfrak{A}(\mathscr{M}_1\cup\mathscr{M}_1')\overline{\otimes}\mathfrak{A}(\mathscr{M}_2\cup\mathscr{M}_2')\subseteq\mathfrak{A}((\mathscr{M}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2)\cup(\mathscr{M}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{M}_2)')$, where $\mathfrak{A}(A)$ stands for the von Neumann algebra generated by the set $A$. But I   did not get the way the authors prove it. For the proof given in the book see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Utd4-YSOZ1H8GLFZY33Oxtu5zhD-8vIq/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Isn't the inclusion $$(\mathscr{Z}_1\overline{\otimes}\mathscr{Z}_2)'\subseteq\mathscr{Z}'$$ obvious, since the commutant of the center is everything?

Comment: The center $\mathscr{Z}$ of a von Neumann algebra $\mathscr{M}$ is defined by $\mathscr{M}\cap\mathscr{M}'$. So $\mathscr{Z}'$ would be the von Neumann algebra generated by $\mathscr{M}\cup\mathscr{M}'$. Could you please elaborate how does the inclusion become obvious?

Comment: Sorry, after reading @Martin's answer I realized the problem is much harder than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your attempt for the easy inclusion, I'm not comfortable enough with tensor products to assess your exchange of tensor and intersection. But that's not needed. Elements of $Z_1\otimes Z_2$ commute with every elementary tensor in $M_1\otimes M_2$, so commute with all elements of the algebraic tensor product, and then commute with limits of these. This shows that
$$
Z_1\otimes Z_2\subset Z.
$$

For the reverse inclusion, what the authors do is to get, from the definition of centre, that
$$\tag1
M_1\otimes M_2\subset Z'.
$$
Then, since every element of $M_1'\otimes M_2'$ commutes with every elements of $M_1\otimes M_2$,
$$\tag2
M_1'\otimes M_2'\subset (M_1\otimes M_2)'\subset Z',
$$
the last inclusion being simply $Z\subset M_1\otimes M_2$. Then,
$$\tag3
Z_1'\otimes Z_2'=(M_1\cap M_1')'\otimes (M_2\cap M_2')'
=(M_1'\cup M_1)''\otimes (M_2'\cup M_2)''\subset Z'.
$$
The last inclusion follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$, because if you have $a\otimes b$ with $a\in M_1'$, $b\in M_2$, then
$$
a\otimes b=(a\otimes 1)(1\otimes b)\in Z'
$$
since $a\otimes 1\in Z'$ by $(2)$ and $1\otimes b\in Z'$ by $(1)$. The other cases are treated similarly, to get $(M_1'\cup M_1)\otimes (M_2'\cup M_2)\subset Z'$. Taking sums and limits in the first coordinate we get $(M_1'\cup M_1)''\otimes (M_2'\cup M_2)\subset Z'$. And then taking sums and limits in the second coordinate, $(3)$ follows.

Finally, from $(3)$ one gets
$$
Z\subset (Z_1'\otimes Z_2')'=Z_1''\otimes Z_2''=Z_1\otimes Z_2. 
$$